# How can i manage sending and reciveing of data from serialport with timer?

Tags: c#, timer, serial-port

I have 3 forms,form1,form2 and form3. I have to perform following things

1. Send data from form1 to serial port.
2. when form1 get value '1', show second form.
3. when click a button in form2 show form3.
4. when click a send button call a function in form1 and send data to serial port.
5. Wait for response.
6. When get a response again send data without clicking the button.
7. wait for response.
8. When get a response again send data without clicking the button.
9. continues this procedure so many times

my problem is that how can I manage this with timer. after getting acknowledgement am sending next data and I stop the timer. But when I get acknowledgement I cant send data, because I already stopped the timer. Is there any solution to this?

---

```
code in form3


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

   {
         int temp =Convert.ToInt32( comboBox1.Text);
        if (comboBox1.Text == "25")
        {
            tempp[0] = 0;

        }
        else if (comboBox1.Text == "30")
        {
            tempp[0] = 1;
        }
        else if (comboBox1.Text == "37")
        {
            tempp[0] = 2;
        }
        int filter = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.Text);
        int asp = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        int prnt = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        int abs = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
        byte[] cmdt = BitConverter.GetBytes(Form1.SETTEMPERATURE);
        byte[] nn = BitConverter.GetBytes(Form1.SETFILTER);
        byte[] len = new byte[1];
        byte[] ERR = new byte[1];
      // byte[] val = new byte[1];
       len[0] = 3;
       ((Form1)this.Owner).SerialPortValueUpdated(len, cmdt, ERR, tempp);

    }

    private void Filter_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }


    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Form1.tflag == 1&&Form1.filflag==0)
        {
            label7.Text = "FILTER...";
              rrr = 1;
        }
        if (Form1.filflag == 1&&Form1.tflag==0)
        {

            label7.Text = "ACK...";
            fltflag = 1;
        }
                  // }
        if (rrr == 1)
        {
           // Form1.tflag = 0;

            byte[] nn = BitConverter.GetBytes(Form1.SETFILTER);
            byte[] len = new byte[1];
            byte[] ERR = new byte[1];
            byte[] val = new byte[1];
            len[0] = 3;
            ((Form1)this.Owner).SerialPortValueUpdated(len, nn, ERR, val);
             timer1.Stop();
        }
        if (fltflag == 1)
        {
            Form1.filflag = 0;
          byte[] nn = BitConverter.GetBytes(Form1.GETRAWADS);
            byte[] len = new byte[1];
            byte[] ERR = new byte[1];
            byte[] val = new byte[1];
            len[0] = 3;
            ((Form1)this. Owner).SerialPortValueUpdated(len, nn, ERR, val);

        }
     }


code in form1

 public  void  SerialPortValueUpdated(byte[]len,byte[]nn,byte[]err,byte[]val)
    {
        byte[] head = new byte[1] { 0xAA };
        byte[] trail = new byte[1] { 0x55 };
        byte[] len2 = len;
        byte[] cmd2 = nn;
        byte[] error = err;
        byte[] value = val;

        serialPort1.Write(head, 0, 1);
        serialPort1.Write(len, 0, 1);
        serialPort1.Write(cmd2, 0, 1);
        serialPort1.Write(error, 0, 1);
        serialPort1.Write(value, 0, 1);
        serialPort1.Write(trail, 0, 1);
        this.Activate();

    }

int bytes = serialPort1.BytesToRead;

        serialPort1.Read(byte_buffer, 0, bytes);

        if (byte_buffer[0] == startup&&count==0)
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {

                this.Invoke(((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {

                    f2 = new Form2();
                    f2.Show(this);
                  //  this.Close();
                })); 
                //  return;
            }


        }
        else if(byte_buffer[0]==0XAA&&flag2!=1)
        {
            flag1 = 1;


        }
count++;
        if (flag1 == 1&& count==2)
        {
            length[0] = byte_buffer[0];
            val = length[0] - 2;
            flag2 = 1;
        }
        if (flag2 == 1&&count==3)
        {
            command[0] = byte_buffer[0];
            flag3 = 1;

        }
        if (flag3 == 1&&count==4)
        {
            error[0] = byte_buffer[0];
            flag4 = 1;
        }
        if (flag4 == 1&&count>4&&byte_buffer[0]!=0X55)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                value[K] = byte_buffer[0];
                flag5 = 1;
                K++;
            }

       }   
      if (command[0] == 3 && flag4==1&&flag5==1&&trailflag==1)
        {
            tflag = 1;
        }
        if (command[0] == 4 && flag4 == 1 && flag5 == 1 && trailflag == 1)
        {
            filflag = 1;
        }
```

Comment: Can any one tell how to update my code?

Comment: @HansPassant:How can I update this?

Comment: You'll get more help if you question easier to read. As it stands, it's not easy at all. Try breaking up the information into small bullet points as a starting point, and then continue from there.

Comment: What exactly is not working? What have you tried? What kind of array is `tempp[]`? Which part needs attention? Please be more specific.

Comment: my problem is that how can I manage this with timer. after getting acknowledgement am sending next data and I stop the timer. But when I get acknowledgement I cant send data, because I already stopped the timer. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: A few notes: what is tempp? What is Form1.SETTEMPERATURE and Form1.SETFILTER? Ok tempp is clearer now since you pass it to a function. What are rrr and fltflag?

Comment: settemperature and set filters are constants that declared in form1.err and fltflags are just two flags..